# Empty recycle bin on user shared folders

Tags: powershell

I'm doing some scripts to clear downloads, scans and recycle bin in user shared folders.

These two commands run fine:

```
Gci C:\Users\"User Shared Folders"\*\Downloads\* | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
Gci C:\Data\*\Scans\* | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

This doesn't work - it doesn't return any results:

```
Gci C:\Users\"User Shared Folders"\*\Desktop\$RECYCLE.BIN\* | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf -Force
```

Comment: ignore the force bit, i was just trying that, dont think its needed

Comment: i now realise that this will just go to my own local recycle bin, so back to square 1

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? On PS 5 you can use the `Clear-RecycleBin` cmdlet.

Comment: Hi its v1 i believe

Comment: We actually cracked it last night with the following script

Gci -Path 'C:\Users\User Shared Folders\' -Filter '$RECYCLE.BIN' -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Whatif

Answer (score 0):

We actually cracked it with the following script

Gci -Path 'C:\Users\User Shared Folders\' -Filter '$RECYCLE.BIN' -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Whatif